$X(t)$ satisfies $E X(1)=0, E X^2(1)=1$, and $X(t) = \sqrt{t} X(1)$ for $t \geq 0$. Use CLT to show $X(t)-X(s)$ is $N(0,|t-s|)$ for $s, t \geq 0$.
The following problem is exercise 13 of section 14 in the book Continuous Time Markov Processes by Ligget
Suppose $X(t)$ is a stochastic process with stationary independent increments that satisfies $E X(1)=0, E X^2(1)=1$, and $X(t)$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{t} X(1)$ for $t \geq 0$. Use the CLT to show that $X(t)-X(s)$ is $N(0,|t-s|)$ for $s, t \geq 0$.
My attempt at a solution (feedback welcome):
Suppose $s < t$ and consider $s = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_{n-1} < t_n  =t$. Then
$$X(t) - X(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X(t_{i+1}) - X(t_i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{t_{i+1}}X(1)- \sqrt{t_i}X(1)$$
Since for each $i$ the increments $\sqrt{t_{i+1}}X(1)- \sqrt{t_i}X(1)$ are i.i.d, and each $\sqrt{t_{i+1}}X(1)- \sqrt{t_i}X(1)$ has finite second moments, we can apply the central limit theorem, to obtain
$$\frac{X(t) - X(s) - 0}{\sqrt{n}}\implies N\left(0, \frac{|t - s|}{n}\right)$$
where $\implies$ refers to converging in distribution. Therefore we have
$$X(t) - X(s)\implies {\sqrt{n}}N\left(0, \frac{|t - s|}{n}\right)$$
and it follows that
$$X(t) - X(s) \implies N\left(0, |t - s|\right)$$
My issue with this proof is that I want to choose $t_i$ so that $\sqrt{t_{i+1}}X(1)- \sqrt{t_i}X(1)$ is i.i.d and so that the central limit theorem gives me $\frac{X(t) - X(s)}{\sqrt{n}}\implies N\left(0, \frac{|t - s|}{n}\right)$. For some reason I am having trouble achieving this.

$\sqrt{t_{i+1}}X(1)- \sqrt{t_i}X(1)$ are not i.i.d.

$X(t_{i+1})$ having the same distribution as $\sqrt{t_{i+1}} X(1)$ does not mean they are equal. Moreover, you also cannot say that $X(t_{i+1}) - X(t_i)$ and $\sqrt{t_{i+1}} X(1) - \sqrt{t_i} X(1)$ have the same distribution.

Just let $(t_i)$ evenly partition $[s,t]$ and then stop at $$X(t)-X(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X(t_{i+1})-X(t_i).$$  You don't have $X(t) = \sqrt{t}X(1)$, so after this point, your solution has a lot of problems.  Instead, just ask yourself how $X(t_{i+1})-X(t_i)$ is distributed (and don't you dare use an equals sign when it's not equal!).

Thank you guys for pointing out my mistakes!!!

Note that $X(0)$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{0} X(1)=0$, so $X(0)=0$.
$X(t_{i+1})-X_(t_i)$ has the same distribution as $X(t_{i+1}-t_i)-X(0) = X(t_{i+1}-t_i)$ which has the same distribution as $\sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i} X(1)$. If $t_{i+1}-t_i = |t-s|/n$ for each $i$, then $X(t)-X(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (X(t_{i+1})-X(t_i))$ is the sum of i.i.d. random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{|t-s|}{n}$. Can you take it from here?

This was incredibly helpful, thank you!
